# Protecting URL patterns within a Web App in Weblogic

Tags: security, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to protect certain resources within a Web-App that's deployed in my weblogic server (12c) through Admin Console. Given below are the steps I followed to accomplish this

1. Security Realms -> my realm (Default Realm) -> Change Security Model Default to "Custom Roles and Policies". Did not restart the server after saving my changes as it prompted me that no restart is necessary
2. Navigated to Home -> Configure Applications -> my app -> Security -> URL Patterns -> Policies and I am not able to add 'URLPatterns'.

It says that I cannot modify security policies if I am using DD Only or Custom Roles.

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I did a restart and that did not fix the issue either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was to protect the resources by adding security constraint to the web.xml as shown below and then create a security group and user name in the default realm within weblogic

```
<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Restricted GET To Employees</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Restricted Access - Get Only</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/restricted/employee/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Employee</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```